# Error al declarar una variable dentro de función al ser llamada

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables

No encuentro dentro de la teoría que conozco, una explicación para la siguiente situación: es un sencillo llamado entre funciones. Al llamar `saludar3` a `obtenerValor`, si la variable `nombre2` está declarada como let, var o const me arroja el error de no estar declarada en `saludar3`. Ahora , si omito el tipo de variable y directamente digo, en `obtenerValor`: `nombre2=prompt("Nombre?");` , `saludar3` la llama y funciona sin problemas.
Agradecería cualquier dato que me ayude a entender este comportamiento.
Muchas gracias.

```
function saludar3(){
    
    obtenerValor();
    console.log(`Hola, ${nombre2}`);
}
 
function obtenerValor(){
    var nombre2=prompt("Nombre?");
    
}

saludar3();  

console.log(nombre2);
```

Comment: Eso es porque si no le pones var o let, se declara como "global"... Por eso puedes acceder a ella por fuera. Pero no es recomendable hacerlo asi, en lo posible es mejor usar let y const y enviar/recibir los valores donde se necesiten

Comment: Muchas gracias,Pipe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que primero llamas a `saludar3()`, luego, esa función llama a `obtenerValor()`, y en la función `obtenerValor()` estás declarando a la variable `nombre2`, en el que solamente podrá serse utilizada en esa función y no afuera, es por eso que cuando tu función `saludar3()` intenta mostrar en consola a tu variable `nombre2`, te dirá que no existe porque no está siendo declarada en esa función.

```js
function saludar3() {
  obtenerValor();
  console.log(`Hola, ${nombre2}`);
}

function obtenerValor() {
  var nombre2 = prompt('Nombre?');
}

saludar3();

console.log(nombre2);
```

En pocas palabras, aquí estás declarando una variable que solo tendrá uso en esta función, no por fuera, es decir, la variable es privada, no tendrás acceso a ella desde fuera, solo en esa función:

```
function obtenerValor() {
  var nombre2 = prompt('Nombre?');
}
```

La solución sería que declares a la variable `nombre2` fuera del todo para que la variable pueda ser accedido desde cualquier función, y en tu función `obtenerValor()` le asignamos su valor a lo que escribamos en el `prompt()`, ejemplo:

```js
var nombre2 = ''; // inicializo a nombre2

function saludar3() {
  obtenerValor(); // llamo a obtenerValor() (aquí ya obtengo al valor de "nombre2").
  console.log(`Hola, ${nombre2}`); // puedo acceder aún a "nombre2" porque es pública, existe.
}

function obtenerValor() {
  nombre2 = prompt('Nombre?'); // el valor de "nombre2" será lo que escribo en el prompt().
}

saludar3();

console.log(nombre2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Cris. Estoy revisando el concepto de Cierres y me queda mucho más claro con tu explicación. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que en tu función otenerValor() tiene declara una variable var, por esto tiene un 'block scope'(limite de alcanze de la variable).

```
function obtenerValor(){
    var nombre2=prompt("Nombre?");
    
}  

console.log(nombre2);
```

Por lo tanto, no te va a funcionar. Te va a decir variable no declarada.
Una de las posible soluciones es:

```
var nombre2 = ''
    function saludar3(){
    
    obtenerValor();
    console.log(`Hola, ${nombre2}`);
}
 
function obtenerValor(){
    nombre2=prompt("Nombre?");
    
}

saludar3();  

console.log(nombre2);
```

De esta manera llamara a la variable nombre2 previamente declarada como una variable global y no local.